# 'Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).run(...) is not a function' in Grunt minified js-file

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, minify, angular-fullstack

My code works on development mode, uncompressed. But when I use grunt's minify functionality and run the app in production mode, I get that error: `Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).run(...) is not a function`.

When I look into the error in Google Chrome Developer Tools, I get what you see in the screenshot. Does anybody understand where the problem is?

[image]

I am using Angular 1.4+ in Angular-Fullstack. The error occurs in `vendor.{{randomstring}}.js`.

Thanks for any support!

Comment: use array syntax for dependency injection.

Comment: Is it necessary everywhere or only in certain cases?

Comment: it is required by DI during minification.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Didn't think of that. Will try and keep you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

1. Dependency injection. You can edit manually the archives or use https://github.com/mgol/grunt-ng-annotate this will do this automagically for you.
2. Concatenation. Check this grunt plugin https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat the issue here is javascript dont understand when a function end/start because dont have a separation mark, check where the error is.

   })(function(a,b) {

It should be:

```
});(function(a,b) {
```

Check the "Concatenating with a custom separator" example of grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: Thanks Danilo. How can I manually inject the dependencies in array annotation when using the controller-as variant with classes and constructors?

Comment: I used `static $inject = ['$scope', ...];` within the class, before the constructor.  I also added the separator to the concat function. Then I built the application again and I still get that error.

Comment: That should be fine. The error is in the same spot? Another way to do the annotations is like this: someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', function($scope, dep1, dep2) {

Comment: Yes, unfortunately nothing has changed in respect to that. Do you have any more ideas? Should I share more code or anything?

Comment: Yes! If you can make a punkler, that would be awesome!

Comment: I'm not sure how to create one for such a big project. Can I reduce it to a number of certain files? Like `dist` and the gruntfile?

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. In any way, i have more experience with gulp. This is a gist of what i use to create the dist files with gulp: https://gist.github.com/dvelasquez/8b03d594851b824e427cf6d49eae068a

Comment: Ok then here is my Gruntfile and the rest will follow tomorrow. Maybe that helps already. https://plnkr.co/edit/ootcKjxijtrt0SbNOuZR?p=info. And thanks for your help - much appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126606/discussion-between-danilo-velasquez-and-molerat).

Comment: This solution worked for me, so I mark it as answer. Nonetheless, I still couldn't get Grunt to concatenate files with the semicolon.